# Lookup method interpreting result

Tags: ansible, lookup

I am using a lookup method which returns a password (using cyberark.. but that is not relevant for this issue description)

When the password happens to contain a curly brace and there is a variable in second lookup parameter, the result is interpreted by jinja.

Here is a simplified example.

Among the inventory variables I have the following values:

```
existing_var: 'just a string'
ansible_password: '{{ lookup("mylookup", "{{ existing_var }}") }}'
```

Where mylookup is a test lookup method, that returns always a single string "x{g{%Y" such as below.
(this has to be stored in the lookup folder specified in the ansible config files, with name "mylookup.py".)

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
__metaclass__ = type
from ansible.errors import AnsibleError
from ansible.plugins.lookup import LookupBase

class LookupModule(LookupBase):
    def run(self, terms, variables=None, **kwargs):
        #we return always the same string without taking account of any parameter.
        return ["x{g{%Y"]
```

I don't expect the lookup result to be interpreted.

But it is.

This lead to an ansible interpretation error : "encountered unknown tag 'Y'.. string: {%Y".

Of course being a password in my real world case, the result is not meant to be interpreted.

I have noticed that this does not occur when there is no curly brace in the lookup second parameter.

```
ansible_password: '{{ lookup("mylookup", "simple string without curly braces.")}}'
```

How to avoid this interpretation?

To solve this issue, I have tried to increase log verbosity, and activated debug. There was no useful log, ansible fails as soon as the lookup method is called.
I have stubbed the complex password lookup method to simplify the issue and present it here.
I have tried to use the filters "safe" and "string", to no avail.
I have removed the second parameter, and observed that in this case, the returned string is not interpreted.

Comment: [moustaches don't stack](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names) => `ansible_password: '{{ lookup("mylookup", existing_var) }}'`. Moreover the curly braces and single quotes in your example are not balanced.

Comment: "_Where `mylookup` is a test lookup ..._" are you [Developing plugins - Lookup plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#lookup-plugins)?

Comment: Still **not** [mre]. See my answer. Does this solve your problem? [edit] the question and make it a minimal and complete example of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"How to avoid this interpretation?"** (of the lookup plugin)*

A: The problem is not caused by the *lookup* plugin. Ansible does not template lookups. See [Unsafe or raw strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#unsafe-or-raw-strings):

> *"When handling values returned by lookup plugins, Ansible uses a data type called unsafe to block templating."*

Create a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── plugins
    └── lookup
        └── mylookup.py

2 directories, 4 files
```

Configure the path to your custom lookup plugin  [DEFAULT_LOOKUP_PLUGIN_PATH](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-lookup-plugin-path)

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/hosts
lookup_plugins = $PWD/plugins/lookup
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

Create the [custom lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#lookup-plugins)

```py
shell> cat plugins/lookup/mylookup.py 
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
__metaclass__ = type

from ansible.plugins.lookup import LookupBase


class LookupModule(LookupBase):
    def run(self, terms, variables=None, **kwargs):
        return ["x{g{%Y"]
```

, simple inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
localhost
```

, and a playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    test_passwd1: "{{ lookup('mylookup') }}"
    test_passwd2: "{{ lookup('mylookup', 'simple string without curly braces') }}"

    test_passwd3: "{{ lookup('mylookup', existing_var) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: test_passwd1
    - debug:
        var: test_passwd2

    - debug:
        var: test_passwd3
      vars:
        existing_var: !unsafe x{g{%Y

    - debug:
        var: test_passwd3
      vars:
        existing_var: x{g{%Y
```

Results:

- Ansible does not template lookups

```yaml
  test_passwd1: "{{ lookup('mylookup') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  test_passwd1: x{g{%Y
```

- There is no difference if you ad a literal parameter. The custom lookup plugin *mylookup* doesn't require a parameter. We add it here to show the expansion of this additional parameter may cause the problem

```yaml
test_passwd2: "{{ lookup('mylookup',
                         'simple string without curly braces') }}"
```

gives the same result

```yaml
  test_passwd2: x{g{%Y
```

- You have to mark ***!unsafe*** a variable that comprises special characters like *`{`* or *`%`* if you want to expand it

```yaml
  existing_var: !unsafe x{g{%Y
  test_passwd3: "{{ lookup('mylookup', existing_var) }}"
```

works fine

```yaml
  test_passwd3: x{g{%Y
```

- If you omit ***!unsafe***

```yaml
  existing_var: x{g{%Y
  test_passwd3: "{{ lookup('mylookup', existing_var) }}"
```

the expansion fails:

> msg: 'An unhandled exception occurred while templating ''{{ lookup(''mylookup'', existing_var) }}''. Error was a <class ''ansible.errors.AnsibleError''>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while templating ''x{g{%Y''. Error was a <class ''ansible.errors.AnsibleError''>, original message: template error while templating string: Encountered unknown tag ''Y''.. String: x{g{%Y. Encountered unknown tag ''Y''.'

---

Note: Test *!unsafe*. Given the file

```bash
shell> cat test_passwd.txt
x{g{%Y
```

- The play below works as expected because Ansible blocks the  templating of the lookup plugins' output

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    test_passwd: "{{ lookup('file', 'test_passwd.txt') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: test_passwd
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  test_passwd: x{g{%Y

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

- The problem also does not appear when you declare a variable is ***!unsafe***. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: test_passwd
      vars:
        test_passwd: !unsafe x{g{%Y
```

gives

```yaml
  test_passwd: x{g{%Y
```

- The task will fail when you omit ***!unsafe***

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: test_passwd
      vars:
        test_passwd: x{g{%Y
```

fails

> msg: 'An unhandled exception occurred while templating ''x{g{%Y''. Error was a <class ''ansible.errors.AnsibleError''>, original message: template error while templating string: Encountered unknown tag ''Y''.. String: x{g{%Y. Encountered unknown tag ''Y''.'